# Python Tkinter Getting value of CheckButton from children list

Tags: python, tkinter

I got widget list of frame with `frame.winfo_children()`. Now I need to get that checkbutton's value.Children List:

> [<tkinter.Label object .!toplevel2.!labelframe.!label>, <tkinter.Entry object .!toplevel2.!labelframe.!entry>, <tkinter.Entry object .!toplevel2.!labelframe.!entry2>, <tkinter.Checkbutton object .!toplevel2.!labelframe.!checkbutton>]

What I tried :

`checkbuttonwidget.get()` , `checkbuttonwidget.cget('variable')`

How can I get its value? And is there any option to use `if` command for split these children?

For example:

```
for wid in frame.winfo_children():
    if wid == LABEL(option?):
        print('yes its a label')
    elif wid == CheckButton(option?):
        print('Its a CheckButton')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to check if the widget is a `Checkbutton` is to use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), then to get the value, you can use `.getvar` and the `widget['variable']` (or `widget.cget('variable')` depending on what you prefer) to get the value of the corresponding variable:

```
for widget in frame.winfo_children():
    if isinstance(widget, tk.Checkbutton):
        value = frame.getvar(widget['variable'])
        print(value)
```

Also depending on how you imported you may need to use `Checkbutton` instead of `tk.Checkbutton`

Useful:

- [`isinstance` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)
- > ```
  > getvar(self, name='PY_VAR')
  >     Return value of Tcl variable NAME.
  > ```